# The new Stack Overflow app doesn't know what day it is

Tags: bug, android-app

I just checked my achievements on the new Stack Overflow app (not the old Stack Exchange one), and while the data it shows seems correct, but it has both yesterday's and today's achievements listed as "Yesterday":

[image]

Technical details:

- App version: 1.0.1 (Edit: I just confirmed this still happens on 1.0.2 too)
- Android version: 5.1.1
- Phone Model: Nexus 4

Comment: As far I can see all of those achievements are from yesterday UTC, but the posts are split by local time, so that may cause some issues?

Comment: That could indeed be the issue. I'm in UTC+3, for future reference for the devs looking into this.

Comment: I've had a couple reports on this but haven't been able to repro it or figure out what's causing it yet. The app gets a flat list of achievement items and bundles/buckets them into those categories, and all the comparisons are done based off UTC dates, but clearly something's off. Investigating...

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi if there's any additional information I can provide that will help you, please ask - I'd be happy to supply it.